# could trezor be used to store passwords like 1 pass?

Tags: storage

I'm wondering if trezor be used to store password(s) like you do with 1pass?
If not, is it something you'd contemplate in developing?

Thank you

Comment: Please note that this site has no connection to the makers or developers of Trezor.  If you have questions or suggestions for them specifically, you should contact their company directly.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It looks like https://trezor.io/support/ is a new page that has an "Ask the Experts" link which points here. Not sure how that's supposed to be different from "Ask the Community" which points to Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

Have not used **1password** or **lastpass**, but the USB-based Trezor hardware device does support:

1. Essentially a 2-factor **keepass** capability. See Trezor Password Manager [**TPM**](https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/passwordmanager.html). TPM works fine across computers using Chrome and having Dropbox accounts.
2. A recoverable Universal Two Factor (U2F) authentication capability (unlike Yubikeys) just like the Ledger Nano. See [**U2F**](https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/u2f.html) for Trezor details. For major sites supporting UTF see this [**Dongle List**](http://www.dongleauth.info/) that is  broken up into different industry verticals.